# (node:6608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EPERM

Tags: angular

While doing "ng serve" I am getting error as" (node:6608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EPERM " . I tried a lot to resolve it but nothing is fruitful as of now. Can anybody help me with the method to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance !

package.json :

{
"name": "mcmfabrics",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"aot": "ng serve --aot"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
"@angular/animations": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/forms": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/localize": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/router": "~11.0.5",
"angular-fusioncharts": "^3.1.0",
"angular-highcharts": "^9.0.11",
"apexcharts": "^3.23.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
"chance": "^1.1.7",
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"chokidar": "^2.0.3",
"d3": "^5.16.0",
"d3-tip": "^0.7.1",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"fusioncharts": "^3.16.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"highcharts": "^8.2.2",
"highcharts-3d": "^0.1.7",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.8.2",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.6",
"ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
"ngx-order-pipe": "^2.1.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.3",
"sanitize-html": "^1.27.5",
"tabletop": "^1.6.2",
"tslib": "^1.14.1",
"xlsx": "^0.15.6",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
"@angular/cli": "^11.0.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
"@angular/language-service": "~11.0.5",
"@types/d3": "^5.16.4",
"@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^5.2.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.15.0",
"typescript": "~4.0.5"
}
}

angular.json:

{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"MCMFabrics": {
"projectType": "application",
"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
"style": "scss"
}
},
"root": "",
"sourceRoot": "src",
"prefix": "app",
"architect": {
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
"outputPath": "dist/MCMFabrics",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts",
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
"tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
"aot": false,

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.scss",
          "src/assets/css/radar.css",
          {
            "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
          }
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/js/jsfunctions.js",
          "node_modules/d3/dist/d3.js",
          "src/assets/js/d3quad.js",
          "src/assets/js/radar.js",
          "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "8mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "MCMFabrics:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "MCMFabrics:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "MCMFabrics:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "tsconfig.app.json",
          "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "MCMFabrics:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "MCMFabrics:serve:production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

},
"defaultProject": "MCMFabrics"
}

Comment: what os are u using? windows? add package.json, angular.json, "ng -v" info in question

Comment: yeah, it's windows have added the required details in the question !

Comment: try to search promblems with angular windows setting, saw something on stack with same error